# IdentityServer oidc-js read errorId

Tags: javascript, identityserver4, openid-connect

Sometimes when I have wrong configuration etc `connect/authorize` redirects to my error page (which is empty for now) with an `errorId`. The question is how to read this `errorId` using oidc-js?
`ErrorId` looks like `CfDJ8ObXvIAxPKdJmO-cyJSfxpRIoVoFa0SgJlnMuaCjX8vgxZ44J4sFm2S4GG6AScjL4XKZGVLv7kEiVXsQIdC7Z4S5Hz1Eyo-5Fp8DDVcU7yecNaJPl4nG8BbY3FpjSxVcLUzP2Ef4FWVCtTDD7M9p97x0W7Ll7Q-_MYdVJ6i1fzQC2Rk_j0hkkbTb-HNIYY9mE8x9jcw0PF0TPSEStlL143HaEocsp5rNsKfaW4lEbamg-lFW0qHfCplC_LvIe2r2XZX1qeRuS6BobcL5e_Avk0R7wNuWViwN2rgzaahyvEJOcEY2fMaLBGjftDCm1uQhST1FIJ60kTX5sFF6NR5CNvp-Y6X8_aEEZ9IEj1ahaVSS`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'errorId' in this context is protected using serverside data protection keys so you can't do anything with it client side. However `identityserver4` does provide a service for handling these errors in the form of `IIdentityServerInteractionService.GetErrorContextAsync(errorId)` so you can implement that in your error controller and return any information you like in the resulting view/output.

Comment: Thank you! I've seen `IIdentityServerInteractionService.GetErrorContextAsync(errorId)` before, but thought it is only used with standard UI, but in custom UI `oidc-js` could decode this. Anyway thanks again!

Comment: Note that by default it uses a cookie to store the error data temporarily but I think it's straightforward to swap this out for an alternative if you need to.